# Make square div aligned to the right-top, minus 50px and responsive

Tags: html, css

I have this card in my dom, it's some thing like :

```
<table id="card">
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content></td>
<table>
```

And i want it to be fixed at right of the screen, minus 50px; I guess that'd be something like `position:fixed; left: calc(100%-50px);`. The problem is that the card stays offscreen, and when i zoom out, it moves around.

This is how it looks (the rest is offscreen):

[image]

this is how i wanted it to look:

[image]

I think its because CSS takes as reference the left of the 'card' to put at the end of screen. If i just put something like `left: calc(90%-50px)`, it moves horizontally when the screen size changes. 
I want if to be fully fixed, right-top,50px away from the border. Is this possible? Or just by using javascript?

Comment: Why can't you use `right: 50px` ?

Comment: the correct formula is `left:calc(100% - width - 50px)` but right:50px is better

Comment: @Turnip The div just gliches out and stays at left-top of the screen

Comment: @TemaniAfif that is nice indeed, but in bigger screens, the card gets more and more distant from the right of the viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think different:

Don't measure from the left side (refers to the *left* side of your element), but from the right:

```
position:fixed; 
right: 50px;
```

This will align the *right*  side of your element 50px from the right border of the viewport.

Comment: I understand that should work :/ but my div either disappears, or glitches out

Comment: did you use `position: fixed`? If yes, add a high `z-index` - maybe it's behind another element (i.e. hidden by it). Not sure what you mean by "glitches out"?

Comment: It is indeed behind my topbar, thanks. But still, by 'glithces out', i mean that the div (witch is a table, is that affecting its behavior?) stays at full left, as if it was `top:0 ; left: 0;`

Comment: well, it can help to give it  `width` setting, otherwise it will get the default `auto` width, which can vary...

Comment: it worked :) the width was indeed covering 100% of the screen (auto), so its contents were aligned to the left, meaning it looked like it was not working. But it did, thanks!